# What methods are available for this kind of RL with partially unknown rewards?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, pomdp, friendly-ai

Let me give an example. There is a king with 1 million subjects. He wants to maximize the discounted sum of future happiness of these subjects. However, he never fully knows their happiness. He can spend some cost c on any given timestep to query the happiness of a single subject (limit 1 per timestep).

Even during training the happiness of the subjects is never known, except via the king spending c, once per timestep.

Are there methods available for this type of problem? I'm reminded of the AI friendliness problem where we want the agent to maximize the agreement between what it does and what humans want it to do, which it can only guess at from partial information.